# How to link a 32 bit MySQL to a 64 bit MS Access?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, 32bit-64bit

I have a program that uses a 32 bit MySQL and I need to read data from it using a 64 bit MS Access. Is it possible to link somehow the server to the MS Access? I tried to use the ODBC driver (both 32 and 64 bit), usually it stops with the error: Malformed package. Any suggestion?

Comment: The 64 bit package should work. The bit size of your MySQL doesn't matter, because your Access communicates it only through the network (even if they are running on the same machine, they communicate as if they would be on a network). Some other problem should happen, probably not the 32-to-64 is the cause. Write more from the exact error message, attach screenshot, etc.

Comment: Until you fix your question, I give you a downvote, a "very low quality" flag and initiate a close vote.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. Tried also from different computer with same software, nope. Since uninstalling the 64 bit office and installing a 32 bit everything works like charm. I don't say that this proofs that the 32/64 bit is the problem but I couldn't find a solution for 64 bit which is a pity.

Comment: By the way thank you for the downvote for not answering your question within 12 horus. Kind of pissed me off. I'm not an IT expert and neither do I have time to be here 24/7. So far I thought that this is a good place to ask questions for non-professionals as well but I might be wrong. Downvote and very low quality... Seriously? 
Cheers...

Comment: I improved your question, you didn't say even a thanks. I explained what you should do, you didn't react. You were even lazy to at least upvote or accept the only answer. What I said in my comment, is essentially the same as the only answer you have got.

Comment: Btw, it is a programming site for programmers, although theoretically even for absolute beginner programmers. Your question is about programming, so you will get your answers from the viewpoint of programmers. For user questions you can get answer on http://superuser.com (your this question is probably ontopic on both sites). Ne legy mar majom :-) attach a screenshot and accept/upvote the answer, and I will change my downvote to an up. Or try the superuser (actually they also like the professional-level questions, despite their name).

Answer (score 1):

64-bit Microsoft Access cannot make use of a 32-bit ODBC driver; you must use a 64-bit ODBC driver for MySQL.

The bitness of the engine powering the target MySQL instance is irrelevant.

"Malformed package" seems like an incomplete error, and may not be related to the connection to MySQL.

Comment: Unfortunately the 64 bit version made this error. So far what I found was that the 64 bit Access exceeds the normal package size of MySQL. Tried to change the packet site to max in MySQL but it didn't help either...

Comment: "package" or "packet"?  These are very different concepts. If you cannot provide exact and complete error messages and other details, nobody can provide you with much help...